# How to upload OpenStack Ubuntu Cloud images to AWS EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, virtual-machine, openstack, amazon-ami

**Context**: Within my OpenStack environment, I'm operating virtual machines instantiated from a [Ubuntu Cloud Image](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/) (QCOW2 format). Now, I want to create snapshots of these virtual machine and operate them within an [AWS EC2 environment](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

**Question**: Which steps do I have to execute for that? Please also be precise where to execute any commands (e.g., within a virtual instance, at the OpenStack controller node, etc.).

**Notes about related posts**:

- [Is it possible to create an ami from an openstack image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451148/is-it-possible-to-create-an-ami-from-an-openstack-image) seems to lack information about how to come to an AMI as requested by Amazon.
- [How do I set up cloud-init on custom AMIs in AWS? (CentOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411408/how-do-i-set-up-cloud-init-on-custom-amis-in-aws-centos?s=1|4.0530) May be obsolete as I use an [Ubuntu Cloud Image](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/)?!
- http://lucasdipaola.blogspot.de/2014/04/importing-openstack-image-into-amazon.html seems to be out-dated and partly also unnecessary for [Ubuntu Cloud Images](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/).

Comment: For RAW images, this also seems to help: http://fosshelp.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-import-kvm-virtual-machine-to.html

Comment: My current strategy is to
(1) convert an OpenStack snapshot (QCOW2) format into a RAW disk image and
(2) bundle it as Amazon image
(following http://lucasdipaola.blogspot.de/2014/04/importing-openstack-image-into-amazon.html)

However, currently step (2) fails since the RAW file becomes too large (43 GB). According to http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/amazon-ec2.html the problem is that I configured my virtual machine to have a partition of 40GB but Amazon only supports Images of size 10GB.

Comment: Trying to down-size the QCOW2 image would destroy the contents of my snapshot -- which is therefore a blocker for me. I will abort my efforts on migrating OpenStack images to EC2 here & will configure an EC2 image from scratch directly within AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images have to be converted to an EC2-compliant format. QCOW2 is such a format and converting existing images to QCOW2 is possible. However, such a conversion does not work for large image files (> 10 GB). Therefore, uploading OpenStack images to EC2 is only possible with high limitations. See my comments above for details.